# Discord bot won't send a message to the channel when a user arrives

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm having issues with the bot not sending a message to a specific channel with the new arrival of users and i tried a lot of things. Here is the code:

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "Random token string"
PREFIX = "!"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = PREFIX, case_insensitive = True)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
   print("it should work")
   await client.get_channel(Int channel ID).send(f"{member.name} has joined")

client.run ("Some random token")
```

I get no errors but what would be the reason that the function for on_member_join not send a message to the specified channel?

Comment: Have you enabled member intents through the developer portal and defined in your code? A member join event requires this even though you may just be sending a message to a channel

Comment: Yeah i enabled all the settings for the bot, basically gave it full admin mode, but apparently it had something to do with the snippet the commenter below gave me, it just magically worked.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have not heard about the **Gateway Intents**. It's pretty "new".

In your case you want to track members when they join a guild so you will need to enable the `Members` Privileged Intent to be able to track it.

Here is a small example on how it should be implemented

```py
intents = discord.Intents().default()
intents.members = True # Enable the member Privileged Intent

# Add the intents to the bot object
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = PREFIX, case_insensitive = True, intents=intents)
```

Make sure you have enabled the member Privileged Intent for your bot on Discord's [application page](https://discord.com/developers/applications).
As you can see in this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucVle.png).

If you need further help here are a few links:

- [discord.py Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)
- [Discord Documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents)

Have a fantastic day and happy coding ^^

Comment: I tried something similar with adding intents but it didnt work, but for some odd reason i added your snippet and finally after all these hours of trying it worked! I really appreciate it thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this should work btw it is called `intents` not `case_insensitive`

```py
from discord import Intents
from discord import Game, Intents
from discord.utils import get
import discord
from discord.ext import commands



@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if member.guild.name == 'server name': #make sure it is right with caps and spaces
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'welcome {member.mention} !\nwelcome to {member.guild.name}',
                    color=0x0061ff)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await client.get_channel(channel id).send(embed=embed) #make sure the channel id is correct
#you can add more of those
    else:
        return
```

Comment: and you also should enable intents in you discord developper portal settings.